# Accessing ng-model from controller getting undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I'm having an 
`<input type="text" ng-model="authorid">` in my html, it gets automatically updated when user updates some other field in the form. It works fine in the html, however trying to access the authorid from the controller it always gets undefined

```
console.log($scope.authorid);
```

... any ideas please?

I have tried numerous solutions here and none worked, especially that I don't want to add another method to set it. Any ideas please?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: you are breaking the golden rule of not having a ***dot*** in `ng-model`. This means it is an object and therefore has inheritance that a primitive doesn't. You are likely losing 2 way binding currently because of this

Comment: I have tried that also by doing two things: 
`<input ng-model="myform.authorid" >` and in my controlled I did two things 
`$scope.myform={};`    
`console.log($scope.myform.authorid);` 
still getting undefined..

Comment: need to show more view code then because it sounds like  a scope problem. Is the input inside a directive with isolated scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending good number of hours trying to understand what's going on. I found the answer here: 
[AngularJS update input manually does not trigger change in the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942509/angularjs-update-input-manually-does-not-trigger-change-in-the-model)

which basically led me to write the following code and that fixed it:

```
var e = document.getElementById("field");
e.value = "my updated value";
var $e = angular.element(e);
$e.triggerHandler('input');
```

Thanks to @Fresheyeball and thanks everyone for trying help as well

Answer (score 0):

You should follow best-practice, and make your `authorid' to a object.property variable.

first, define in your controller, something like:

```
$scope.form = {};
```

then in your html, do:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="form.authorid">
```

This is because in AngularJS, a child scope normally prototypically inherits from its parent scope.

Comment: I have done that as per my comment above and still not able to get its value.