# HTML input element does not recognize value when I put value programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a Google Chrome extension that retrieves data from one site and paste the data in another site.

To get the data from the first site I use this code:

```
$('#copy').click(function() {   
       var newClipboard = {
      "name": $('#buyercontactname').val(),
  }
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({newClipboard: newClipboard});
});
```

To paste the data in another site I use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.paste) {
            if (!(request.clipboard.name === '')) {
                var nameParts = request.clipboard.name.split(' ');
                $('[id="shippingFirstName"]').val(nameParts[0])
                $('[id="shippingLastName"]').val(nameParts[1]);
            }
          }
        }
    });
});
```

I replace the `id` value regarding the second site `div` or `input`.

## The problem:

If I paste the value on `div` it works great, but If I paste the value on `input` is not recognized and I need to press on a key for that.

**For example:**

After I paste the values:

[image]

After I click "Save" (I get an error the fields are empty):

[image]

After I press a key on the fields (even I press on "space"):

[image]

The `input` elemant look like this:

```
<input ng-model="user.first_name" id="shippingFirstName" name="shippingFirstName" prefix-attrs-with="shipping" value="" pattern="(?!^\d+$)^.+$" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" xo-error-tooltip="" ng-required="true" data-test-id="user.first_name" class="ng-pristine ng-empty ng-valid-pattern ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength hasErrorTooltipRequired ng-touched focused" required="required" aria-describedby="nbafrxk" aria-invalid="true">
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: It was answered a few times, in short try these - 1) document.execCommand with `insertText`, 2) $(el)[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true})) - maybe also for 'input'.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! but I didn't understand, can you explain more...?

Comment: Try with document.querySelector('[id="shippingFirstName"]').value=nameParts[0]; instead of $('[id="shippingFirstName"]').val(nameParts[0])

Comment: @ChinmoySamanta the same result :(

Comment: Use focus method after setting value of input elements. Eg: document.querySelector('[id="shippingFirstName"]').focus()

Comment: @ChinmoySamanta Thank you but still doesn't work :(

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Can you share an sample example?

Comment: @ChinmoySamanta what do you mean example?

Comment: If it works when you do a keypress, why not invoke a keypress event?

Comment: @Katie.Sun I tried it but doesn't work,  I updated my question, please check. thanks!

Comment: looking at the input code, are you using AngularJS? If so, you should probably be updating the input field via the angular model, not jquery

Comment: If so, please share the controller and template files used, unless the page you are pasting into is not within your control. In which case, you may be SOL.

Comment: @mix3d It's google chrome extension, the angular is not within my control :/ I tried to set the value on someone else site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create and dispatch an input event after setting the value of input box.You can get information about input event from this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input).

```
document.querySelector('[id="shippingFirstName"]').value=nameParts[0];
document.querySelector('[id="shippingLastName"]').value=nameParts[0];
document.querySelector('[id="shippingFirstName"]').dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true }));
document.querySelector('[id="shippingLastName"]').dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question: [val() doesn't trigger change() in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179385/val-doesnt-trigger-change-in-jquery)

In summary, it looks like `.val()` by itself might not trigger the text field's change event, but you can trigger it manually by running this after you change the value:

```
$('[id="shippingFirstName"]').trigger("change");
```

If `change()` doesn't trigger it, you could try a bigger list of events to trigger the change in the put field:

```
$('[id="shippingFirstName"]').keydown();
$('[id="shippingFirstName"]').keypress();
$('[id="shippingFirstName"]').keyup();
$('[id="shippingFirstName"]').focus();
```

Comment: I understood the direction, but unfortunately it does not help. I might need something that really resembles a real click on the input.

Comment: If you just need to click it, has using `.click()` on the element worked before/after inputting the text?

Comment: I&#39;ve updated the answer to include a larger list of events. If one of those doesn&#39;t work, you could try a more [exhaustive list on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#Standard_events).

Comment: Still doesn't work :( I updated my question, please check.

Comment: Ah, your form is definitely using Angular as a previous commenter noted. Try taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942509/angularjs-update-input-manually-does-not-trigger-change-in-the-model#22942828).