# Write text to a input field?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

Here is the following code;

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">        
  <input id="Shipping_FirstName" name="firstname" ng-model="userOrder.Shipping.FirstName" type="text" class="form-control nsg-form--input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength" ng-class="{'is-invalid': shipping_subform.$submitted &amp;&amp; shipping_subform.firstname.$invalid}" required="" maxlength="35" tooltip="Please enter your first name" tooltip-toggle="shipping_subform.$submitted===true &amp;&amp; shipping_subform.firstname.$invalid===true" esw-google-analytics-blur="">        <!-- ngIf: shipping_subform.$submitted && shipping_subform.firstname.$invalid -->    
</div>
```

I have tried the following which writes the text to the input field;

```
document.getElementById("Shipping_FirstName").value = "test"
document.querySelector("input[id='Shipping_FirstName']").value = "test";
```

**However**, when I press the submit button, it says *"Please enter your first name"* as if the code above actually didn't write the text.

How can I fix this?

Thanks for any help, it's all appreciated.

Comment: why arent you using the ng-model

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942509/angularjs-update-input-manually-does-not-trigger-change-in-the-model

Comment: I am new to javascript and modern dom/jquery. What is ng-model and it's importance?

Comment: It is angular.... What you are doing is not the angular way

Comment: damm I am not sure if angular is going to work with the function evaluateJavascript in swift.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to epascarello, the answer is;

```
var e = document.getElementById("Shipping_FirstName");
e.value = "test";
var $e = angular.element(e);
$e.triggerHandler('input');
```