# Change input value using javascript in a form built with Aura

Tags: javascript, aura-framework

I have an input in a form built with aura (Salesforce JS framework):

```
<input class=" input uiInput uiInputText uiInput--default uiInput--input" type="text" aria-describedby="5284:0" placeholder="" id="7:4790;a" data-aura-rendered-by="17:4790;a" data-aura-class="uiInput uiInputText uiInput--default uiInput--input" data-interactive-lib-uid="54" aria-required="true">
```

I need to change the value of this input using javascript.
However, when doing:

```
document.getElementById("7:4790;a").value = "random value";
```

Visually, it changes the value in the input, but it is not taken into account when saving as if I didn't change anything.

How can I achieve this ?
Do I need to trigger a specific event so that aura takes notice of the new data ?

Comment: The `change` event can be used here.  [See @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange)

Comment: I don't know "aura" at all. But I can guess that the framework is listening to the input events so it's not enough to just change the value. There is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22942828/863110) maybe it can give you a direction to the solution. Also, there is dedicated stackexchange [site for salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/) maybe they could give you better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an attribute of string type.

```
<aura:attribute name="myInputValue" type="String" />
```

Pass the attribute to the value property of the input tag.

```
<input .... value="{! v.myInputValue}" />
```

Now, whenever you want to change the value in the input, you can simply do this from your javascript function:

```
component.set('v.myInputValue, "My new String" />
```

Important Note: Salesforce frameworks don't allow DOM level manipulation due to a security architecture called Locker service. It is not advisable to follow DOM level Manipulation. Instead, follow the state-based approach like above.